# Can't install docker for windows 10 64bit pro, error "this app cant run on your pc"

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

So I downloaded docker from the official website and when I try to install I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with the software's publisher as the Windows message suggests?

Comment: are you 100% sure you meet *all* of these requirements?  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Comment: I had docker installed previously on this pc. I just re-installed windows. The problem is that I can't even open the install dialog.

Comment: @Totty.js ok, you reinstalled Windows, is iy fully patched to 1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or later?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that error is displayed for binaries that are an incompatible instruction set with the operating system. You'll get it with 16-bit (DOS or Win16) binaries on 64-bit Windows, 64-bit binaries on 32-bit Windows, and ARM or Itanium binaries (or other now-rare platforms that Windows used to support) on any x86-based system. Make very sure that you are installing the correct version for your computer. For example, since you reinstalled Windows recently, make sure you installed 64-bit Windows (32-bit Windows can't run 64-bit apps, even if using a 64-bit CPU).

Another possibility might be if you enabled software restrictions - especially if you configured your machine in Windows 10 S mode - in which case you'll get an error if you try to run software from an untrusted source (such as downloaded from the Internet). That's an unlikely answer, but "I reinstalled Windows and now I can't run a program I could before" is an unlikely problem.

Comment: Thanks, has been solved by downloading again. Not sure how it happened. My machine is 64bit and worked before so is very strange.